# onSnapshot conflicts with orderBy and where

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am building restaurants reviews app with react native cli.
To attach the real time listener on reviews collection, I created 'reviews' collection.

All the reviews in the application, posted by different users, will be stored as individual document in this collection. Each document will contain the restaurant_id so as seen in the codes below, in fetchReviews function, the passed restaurantId will be used to match and fetch the respective restaurant's reviews and render in the restaurant detail screen.

But the issue is after I put orderBy after where query, the real time listener is not working and not fetching the reviews or updating in real time. If I remove the orderBy, it works okay but the fetched reviews will be random in the client side. I want to sort them by timestamp - 'createdAt'.

```
export const fetchReviews = restaurantId => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const reviewsRef = firestore()
      .collection('reviews')
      .where('restaurant_id', '==', restaurantId);

    const unsubscribe = reviewsRef.onSnapshot(async querySnapshot => {
      try {
        const reviews = [];

        for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
          const reviewData = doc.data();

          // Check if the reviewData has an "images" field before mapping
          if (reviewData.images) {
            const reviewImageUrls = await Promise.all(
              reviewData.images.map(async image => {
                try {
                  const imageRef = await storage().ref(image);
                  return imageRef.getDownloadURL();
                } catch (imageError) {
                  // Handle the case where a detail image is not found
                  // Use the default logo image URL to fill the array
                  const defaultLogoRef = await storage().ref(
                    '/default_logo.png',
                  );
                  return defaultLogoRef.getDownloadURL(); // Return the default URL directly
                }
              }),
            );
            reviewData.images = reviewImageUrls;
          }

          reviews.push(reviewData);
        }
        dispatch(fetchRestaurantReviewsSuccess({restaurantId, reviews}));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe; // Return the unsubscribe function in case you want to stop listening later
  };
};
```

Tried to find the cause and it was the 'orderBy' part.
After removing it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like adding the `orderBy` leads to the query needing a composite index that doesn't exist. If that happens, the SDK will raise an error message with a link to create the exact index you need.

So look for the error message (add `try-catch` around the call to Firestore to make sure you catch it), and click that link. This will take you to the Firestore console screen with all necessary fields filled out already - so you should just have to click a button to create it.

Comment: `try-catch` around a Firestore `onSnapshot` won't do much, you'd need to attach an `onerror` listener as the second argument after the `onnext` listener that's handling the data.

Comment: Good point Sam. Feel like editing my answer to include that code sample? 